# Deploying Multiple chaincodes on same channel using hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Can anyone help me in in-depth explanation on how to deploy multiple chaincodes onto the single channel in hyperledger-fabric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it takes is using a different chaincode name (but the same channel name) while installing the chaincode. Look for the `--name` argument in the [CLI documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/commands/peerlifecycle.html).
Use the same chaincode name again when querying/invoking the chaincode.
See also the [official tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/deploy_chaincode.html).